# Firefox add-on: Populating sqlite database with a lot of data (around 80000 rows) not working with executeSimpleSQL()

Tags: csv, sqlite, firefox-addon

The firefox add-on that I am trying to code needs a big database.

I was advised not to load the database itself from the 'data' directory (using the addon-sdk to develop locally on my linux box).

So I decided to get the content from a csv file and insert it into the database that I created.

The thing is that the csv has about 80 000 rows and I get an error when I try to pass .`executeSimpleSQL()` the reaaaaally long `INSERT` statement as a string

```sql
('insert into table
  values (row1val1,row1val2,row1val3),
         (row2val1,row2val2,row2val3),
         ...
         (row80000val1,row80000val2,row80000val3)')
```

Should I insert asynchronously? Use prepared statements?
Should I consider another approach, loading the database as an sqlite file directly?

Answer (score 0):

You cannot use that many records in a single INSERT statement;
SQLite limits the number to its internal parameter [SQLITE_LIMIT_COMPOUND_SELECT](http://www.sqlite.org/limits.html#max_compound_select), which is 500 by default.

Just use multiple INSERT statements.

Answer (score 0):

You may be crossing some sqlite limits.

From sqlite [Implementation Limits](http://www.sqlite.org/limits.html):

### Maximum Length Of An SQL Statement

> The maximum number of bytes in the text of an SQL statement is limited
> to SQLITE_MAX_SQL_LENGTH which defaults to 1000000. You can redefine
> this limit to be as large as the smaller of SQLITE_MAX_LENGTH and
> 1073741824.
>
> If an SQL statement is limited to be a million bytes in length, then
> obviously you will not be able to insert multi-million byte strings by
> embedding them as literals inside of INSERT statements. But you should
> not do that anyway. Use host parameters for your data. Prepare short
> SQL statements like this:
>
> `INSERT INTO tab1 VALUES(?,?,?);`
>
> Then use the sqlite3_bind_XXXX()
> functions to bind your large string values to the SQL statement. The
> use of binding obviates the need to escape quote characters in the
> string, reducing the risk of SQL injection attacks. It is also runs
> faster since the large string does not need to be parsed or copied as
> much.
>
> The maximum length of an SQL statement can be lowered at run-time
> using the sqlite3_limit(db,SQLITE_LIMIT_SQL_LENGTH,size) interface.